# How do I "echo" a function results into another function?

Tags: php, function, syntax, echo

I have this function :

```
function MakeInput($id, $class) {
    $value = substr($id, 2);
    global $$value;
    echo '<input type="text" id="'.$id.'" name="'.$id.'" class="'.$class.'" value="'.htmlentities($$value,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8').'" />';
}
```

Which do not return but echoes the results.

I'd like to use it as it is into another function:

```
function ItkMakeMo($NomDebVar) {
$Output = '
    <tr>    
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>'.MakeInput($NomDebVar.'moshj','IntInput').'</td>
    </tr>
';
echo $Output;
```

}

So this solution doesn't work, PHP sends the MakeInput output before the "echo $Output"

Comment: It seems to me you don't understand how using functions? http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Comment: Great, 3 answers exactly the same in 30 secs, a new record????

Comment: He may have another reason for asking to use the function "as is" though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some reason you can't change `MakeInput()` or it would take more effort than it's worth to change it, then you can echo the output directly from `ItkMakeMo()`:

```
function ItkMakeMo($NomDebVar) {
echo '
    <tr>    
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>';

MakeInput($NomDebVar.'moshj','IntInput');

echo '</td>
    </tr>
';
}
```

Then the `MakeInput()` output would be in the right place.

If possible, it's usually better not to directly output in functions and instead return the output as a string, then you can output it when you call the function.

Answer (score 5):

You should `return` the value:

```
function MakeInput($id, $class) {
    $value = substr($id, 2);
    global $$value;
    return '<input type="text" id="'.$id.'" name="'.$id.'" class="'.$class.'" value="'.htmlentities($$value,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8').'" />';
}
```

And later `echo` it.

Answer (score 1):

as opposed to using echo in your function, use return:

```
function MakeInput($id, $class) {
    $value = substr($id, 2);
    global $$value;
    return '<input type="text" id="'.$id.'" name="'.$id.'" class="'.$class.'" value="'.htmlentities($$value,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8').'" />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to return string in function MakeInput instead of echoing it,

```
function MakeInput($id, $class) {
    $value = substr($id, 2);
    global $$value;
    return '<input type="text" id="'.$id.'" name="'.$id.'" class="'.$class.'" value="'.htmlentities($$value,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8').'" />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case, I'd try to echo the output right away, without storing it in a variable first.

```
function ItkMakeMo($NomDebVar) {
echo '
    <tr>    
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>';
MakeInput($NomDebVar.'moshj','IntInput').'</td>
echo '    </tr>
';
}
```

But as stated by others, it would definitely be best to change the function to return the value, rather than echoing it. Not just in this case, but as a general best practice. So only try this if you cannot change MakeInput yourself for some reason.

Comment: This would still output the `MakeInput()` string before the `ItkMakeMo()` string, since the `MakeInput()` is `echo`ing, and is not something you can concatenate.

Comment: That's a good point @Aether, I've changed the function to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function MakeInput($id, $class) {
    $value = substr($id, 2);
    global $$value;
    return '<input type="text" id="'.$id.'" name="'.$id.'" class="'.$class.'" value="'.htmlentities($$value,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8').'" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first function change echo with return:

```
function MakeInput($id, $class) {
    $value = substr($id, 2);
    global $$value;
    return '<input type="text" id="'.$id.'" name="'.$id.'" class="'.$class.'" value="'.htmlentities($$value,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8').'" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you would not like to modify the MakeInput function, use Output buffering.

```
function ItkMakeMo($NomDebVar) {
    ob_start();
    MakeInput($NomDebVar.'moshj','IntInput');
    $input = ob_get_clean();
    $Output = '
        <tr>    
            <td>Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>'.$input.'</td>
        </tr>
    ';
    echo $Output;
}
```

If you don't need the $output variable but need MakeInput to echo, I'd follow what Rob suggested. With that said, follow what everyone else wrote because this is just an ugly way around poor programming.

Comment: This solution does work but the MakeInput still outputs before the ob_get_flush()

Comment: I would use `$input = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();` if taking this approach. `ob_get_flush();` outputs the content of the buffer when called.
Edit: Good call, @Phil R.: `ob_get_clean()` does both in one.